# Python Error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

Here is the error:

File "f**.py", line 34, in module

```
url_type = url.split('-')[0][-2:] #
```

Here is the whole block:

```
fit_urls = []
for event_url in event_urls: 
  print event_url
  try:
    sock = urllib.urlopen(event_url)
    event_html = sock.read()
    event_soup = BeautifulSoup(event_html)

    tds = event_soup.find_all('td')
    for td in tds:
        for link in td.find_all('a'):
            url = link.get('href')
            url_type = url.split('-')[0][-2:] letters
            if url_type == 'ht': 
                #print url
                fit_urls.append(url)

except HTTPError:
    pass
```

`

Comment: There were no links. `link.get` produced `None` because there was no `'href'` in it.

Comment: it looks like `url = link.get('href')` is returning `None` i.e. no url is found in the link (or no `link` is found, depending on how the library behaves)

Answer (score 0):

That is because any of your `'link'` is not having the `'href'` attribute. You may verify it by adding `print link` before doing `url = link.get('href')`.

In order to fix this, you may add a additional `if` check to filter such links as:

```
for td in tds:
    for link in td.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if url:   # additional check. will be `False` when `'url'` will be `None`
            url_type = url.split('-')[0][-2:] letters
            # Your rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `url = link.get('href')` is returning `None`. You can check for `None` in your loop:

```
for td in tds:
    for link in td.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if not url:
            continue
        url_type = url.split('-')[0][-2:] letters
        if url_type == 'ht': 
            #print url
            fit_urls.append(url)
```